# UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:zlib" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme)

Tags: webpack

Anyone can help resolve this error? I have tried resolving using polyfills and every other solution i could find online and think by myself but i still keep getting the issues

Answer (score 4):

#### Option A

I also encountered this issue when using `node-fetch: ^3.0.0` but downgrading to `node-fetch: ^2.0.0` resolved it for me.

---

#### Option B

You need to declare these as `externals`. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

**Webpack 4**

```
  target: node
```

**Webpack 5**

```
  externalsPresets: { node: true },
```

I also use [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) but this might not apply in your case.

Related issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13290

Comment: Adding `externalPresets` worked for me with ease, thank you!!