# Error: node:stream/promises - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError

Tags: node.js, node-streams

```
import minifyXML from 'minify-xml'

this.outputLongText = minifyXML(this.inputLongText)
```

When i using minify-xml then occour error:

```
node:stream/promises - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:stream/promises" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

node:stream - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:stream" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
```

I using node v18.17.0, angular 16.1.7.
How to fix this?

Comment: maybe this StackOverflow Answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71808381/2681480